# Load 360 degree Youtube video using VrVideoView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, google-cardboard, google-vr

I want to stream a 360 video from YouTube in my android app using `VrVideoView`. I have searching about this for some time but haven't really found a question with accepted or highly voted answer. Even on [google developer website](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView), I only found this statement.

> A remote URL with a http or https scheme, such as "http://foo.com/file.mp4". HLS URLS (e.g. "http://foo.com/file.m3u8") are supported but require the correct input format to be set in the VrVideoView.Options object.

Someone please help me figure out whether it is possible or not? If possible, then How do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the options object, you can use

```
    Options options = new Options();
    options.inputFormat = Options.FORMAT_HLS;
    options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO; // for 360 video
    // options.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER; //for 3D 360 video
    videoWidgetView.loadVideo(youtubeURI, options);
```

For more reference, you can refer to documentation available at [Google VR](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView.Options)

or refer to the simple video widget sample in Google VR SDK

Comment: How do I form a URI from a youtube video link?? I tried by simply using the url of video but it didn't work.

Comment: Uri youtubeUri = Uri.parse("www.youtube.com/someDummyVideo");

Comment: @shivamDev no it did not work. I have not found any solution for this problem yet.

Comment: @Exception So what you are doing right now? Just playing it from server URL or what?

Comment: @shivamDev Yes, and for youtube videos sending an Intent to youtube to open it in their app.

Comment: @Exception Okay. I don't want to open it in youtube app so streaming it from my own server url

Answer (score 0):

to play video in VrVideoView you need to get the direct url to video, you can do this with tool like youtube-dl but this tool needs python, try to find another way to get the url